# Discord.js V13 Adding role when using a slash command

Tags: discord.js, roles

I am trying to code a bot that when you use a certain slash command, it gives you a role. I have looked for a solution but haven't been able to find one. Nothing is seeming to work for me, i keep getting errors about the code, like "message not found, did you mean Message"

This is my first time trying to code a bot so if its a dumb issue, please bear with me.

Here is my code:

```
import DiscordJS, { Intents, Message, Role } from 'discord.js'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const client = new DiscordJS.Client({
intents: [
  Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
  Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
],
})

// Slash Commands

//ping pong command

client.on('ready', () => {
console.log('BOT ONLINE')

//bot test server
const guildId = '868857440089804870'
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId)
const role = client.guilds.cache.find(r => r.name == "Test Role to 
give")

let commands




if (guild) {
  commands = guild.commands
} else {
  commands = client.application?.commands
}




commands?.create({
  name: 'ping',
  description: 'says pong'
})


commands?.create({
  name: "serverip",
  description: 'Gives user the server IP'
})

commands?.create({
  name: "giverole",
  description: 'Gives user the role'
})


})

client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
if(!interaction.isCommand()) {
  return
}

const { commandName, options } = interaction
//This is the role id that i want to give
const role = '884231659552116776'
//these are the users that i want to give the role to
const sniper = '725867136232456302'
const josh = '311981346161426433'

if (commandName === 'ping') {
  interaction.reply({
    content: 'pong',
    ephemeral: true,
  })
} else if (commandName === 'serverip') {
interaction.reply({
  content: 'thisisserverip.lol',
  ephemeral: true,
 })
} else if (commandName === 'giverole') {
  interaction.reply({
    content: 'Role given',
    ephemeral: true,
    
   })
  }
 })

 client.login(process.env.test)
```

Comment: Hey and welcome :D I'm sorry but this is not a place where we write code for you. We can help you find bugs in your existing code, but you have to try to implement your ideas by yourself ^^

Comment: I edited it to now have my code

Answer (score 2):

You can just simply retrieve the [`Interaction#Member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Interaction?scrollTo=member) and add the role to them using [`GuildMemberRoleManager#add`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add) method!

```js
const role = client.guilds.cache.find(r => r.name == "Test Role to 
give");

await interaction.member.roles.add(role); // and you're all set! welcome to stackoverflow
```

Comment: When i put this in, it gave me these errors:
 No overload matches this call.
',' expected

Comment: Would it matter that i put the "interaction.member.roles.add(role);" in a if statement?

Comment: It shouldn't, maybe try importing GuildMember from discord.js

Comment: like this, right? 
import GuildMember from 'discord.js'

Comment: Correct let me know if that fixes it

Comment: does it matter that im using TS?

Comment: Actually does, you need to import base objects directly from discord.js as they're unavailable to your environmental / compiling runtime at that point sooooo actually looking into the error might help, so could you attach the full error and stack trace?

Comment: @Zero You don't have to await the `.find()` function since the cache is already available (which is the purpose of a cache) and `.find()` is a simple function of a **collection** (which returns no promise). Instead, you have to await the `[...].roles.add()` line because `.add()` retuns a promise :)

Comment: And @ConnorBrown you don't have to import GuildMember ^^ There's like no case where you need to do that

Comment: Also if you ever do need to import GuildMember it's `import { GuildMember } from "discord.js"` (don't forget the curly braces)

Comment: I got it now... Thanks for your help... will definitely be coming back to this website if i need help again

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (commandName === 'giverole') {
  const role = client.guilds.cache.find(r => r.name == "Ahmed1Dev")
  await user.roles.add(role)
  message.channel.send("Done Added Role For You") // Fixed By Ahmed1Dev
}
```